# Analyse CAN signals in CANoe tests

Tags: plot, automated-tests, signal-processing, canoe

When running tests via the CANoe test environment, I can check the instantaneous value of a signal using e.g. `checkSignalInRange()`. For some signals it would make more sense to evaluate typical physical attributes like amplitude, frequency, period and mean value. Is there a way to do it in CANoe?

As an acceptable workaround, is it possible to set up some signals to be recorded during a test, and include the signal plot into the test report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any check functions for checking frequency, period, etc.

You can include a signal plot, by adding a graphics window plotting the signal of interest to your measurement setup, and add a screenshot of it to the test report by calling
`TestReportAddWindowCapture`

Answer (score 1):

You have to install an additional CANoe option called **.Scope**, which provides you the access to Physical Layer of every Comm Channel configured in that particular CANoe Config.

https://vector.com/vi_canoe_canalyzer_scope_en.html

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant: I'm interested in logical signals (values periodically transmitted on the bus) rather than CAN physical level. Still, thanks for posting this, I didn't know such a feature existed.